# Google Cloud App Engine: Is there an API or SDK call to disable/enable an app (python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, automation

I have been reading through the docs but am unable to find any direction on how to enable or disable the actual app.

I attempt to run a python program that takes anywhere from 5 minutes to 1 hour to process. Looking automate the process of enabling the app before the processing begins and disabling once it is done.

Any tips are appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enable/Disabling an App Engine application is pretty straightforward process from the Cloud Console.

Simply refer to [these steps as per the public documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/console#disabling_an_application). Notice that the procedure simply consists on clicking on a button on the Applications settings page in the Cloud Console. Once the application is disabled if you want to go back to Enable the application simply go back to the same page and click on the same button (which should display Enable application, instead of Disable application).

Achieving this task programmatically is  definitely a bit trickier. Nonetheless it could be achieved with the [App Engine Admin API](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/admin-api/reference/rest) and it's client libraries, more specifically by taking advantage of the [apps.patch method](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/admin-api/reference/rest/v1/apps/patch).

There is a complete [example for disabling an application](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/managing-costs#disable_your_app_programmatically) on the documentation using a Cloud Function with Python Runtime. It is based on budget alerts, but you could modify it as per your specific needs and establish the condition you want to trigger the Cloud Function.

I would create two different Cloud Functions. One for enabling the app and another one for disabling the app. The most relevant part of the code will be this (but check the [example described](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/managing-costs#disable_your_app_programmatically) for the details):

a. To disable the function

```
import os
from googleapiclient import discovery
APP_NAME = os.getenv('GCP_PROJECT')

def limit_use_appengine():

    if [CHANGE CONDITION AS PER YOUR NEEDS]:
        print(f'No action necessary.')
        return

    appengine = discovery.build(
        'appengine',
        'v1',
        cache_discovery=False
    )
    apps = appengine.apps()

    # Get the target app's serving status
    target_app = apps.get(appsId=APP_NAME).execute()
    current_status = target_app['servingStatus']

    # Disable target app, if necessary
    if current_status == 'SERVING':
        print(f'Attempting to disable app {APP_NAME}...')
        body = {'servingStatus': 'USER_DISABLED'}
        apps.patch(appsId=APP_NAME, updateMask='serving_status', body=body).execute()
```

b. enable the application

```
import os
from googleapiclient import discovery
APP_NAME = os.getenv('GCP_PROJECT')

def enable_use_appengine():

    if [CHANGE CONDITION AS PER YOUR NEEDS]:
        print(f'No action necessary.')
        return

    appengine = discovery.build(
        'appengine',
        'v1',
        cache_discovery=False
    )
    apps = appengine.apps()

    # Get the target app's serving status
    target_app = apps.get(appsId=APP_NAME).execute()
    current_status = target_app['servingStatus']

    # Disable target app, if necessary
    if current_status == 'USER_DISABLED':
        print(f'Attempting to enable app {APP_NAME}...')
        body = {'servingStatus': 'SERVING'}
        apps.patch(appsId=APP_NAME, updateMask='serving_status', body=body).execute()
```

I haven't tested the codes themselves. But I believe they will work. It is very important for you to know that disabling an App Engine application will stop the charges related for the app serving requests, nonetheless if you use Datastore or Cloud Storage or any other product to store some data generated by your app those charges will still accrue.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I will be giving it a try today and see how it goes.

Answer (score 0):

As of python 3.8 this code no longer works due to the removal of the GCP_PROJECT environment variable, also Google's code doesnt allow for testing the cloud function, which I added as well

```
import base64
import json
import os
from googleapiclient import discovery

import google.auth
_, project_id = google.auth.default()

APP_NAME = project_id

def limit_use_appengine(data, context):
    if 'data' in data.keys():
        pubsub_data = base64.b64decode(data['data']).decode('utf-8')
        pubsub_json = json.loads(pubsub_data)
    else:
        pubsub_json = data
    cost_amount = pubsub_json['costAmount']
    budget_amount = pubsub_json['budgetAmount']
    if cost_amount <= budget_amount:
        print(f'No action necessary. (Current cost: {cost_amount})')
        return

    appengine = discovery.build(
        'appengine',
        'v1',
        cache_discovery=False
    )
    apps = appengine.apps()

    # Get the target app's serving status
    target_app = apps.get(appsId=APP_NAME).execute()
    current_status = target_app['servingStatus']

    # Disable target app, if necessary
    if current_status == 'SERVING':
        print(f'Attempting to disable app {APP_NAME}...')
        body = {'servingStatus': 'USER_DISABLED'}
        apps.patch(appsId=APP_NAME, updateMask='serving_status', body=body).execute()
```